# Affine property of multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is there a 'direct' proof not involving the Fourier inversion formula for the fact that if $X$ is a multivariate Gaussian and $A$ is a matrix (not necessarily square, not necessarily invertible) then $AX$ is a multivariate Gaussian as well?

Im am not talking about the actual parameters (mean and covariance matrix) as one can 'easily' compute them. I am talking about there mere fact that $AX$ is multivariate normally distributed.
 Depending on the direction from which one comes, one can define 'being multivariate Gaussian' in different ways. For me, the definition is
  $$ X = AZ + b$$
where $A$ is some matrix, $b$ is some vector and $Z$ is a vector of iid. standard univariate Gaussians.
I know that there is the characterization that
$$
\begin{align*}
  & X ~\text{is multivariate Gaussian} \\
  & \iff \text{each linear combination of the $X_i$ is univariate Gaussian}
\end{align*}
$$
which would imply the desired result easily but how does one prove '$\Leftarrow$'? I guess that the proof also uses characteristic functions, is that right?

Refernces, pointers and hints are highly welcome :-)

Thanks in advance,

FW

Comment: The "iff" condition you call a characterization is actually the definition of being multivariate normal. Thus, the task is to show that, if every $t'X$ is univariate normal then every $t'AX=(A't)'X$ for $t$ of the correct size, is univariate normal... which seems rather direct, no?

Comment: @Did... ok, we have a misunderstanding here: My definition is: 'X = AZ + b' where Z is iid. standard univariate Gaussian. What I'm asking for is 'every linear combination is univariate Gaussian' ==> 'X = AZ + b' with X iid. univariate standard Gaussian. I'll edit.

Comment: @Did: the reason I use this definition is that I am actually interested in the density and I just know how to get from this definition to the density :-)